# Lost ls directory highlighting after a crash

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, terminal

Normally commands such as `ls` and `grep` offer nice syntax highlighting for me. But my system crashed (running an ubuntu VM) and after I restarted, I no longer have this highlighting, it's all a dreary grey.

Nano, however, notably does do it's normal highlighting.

I don't know where to start looking for why I don't have directory highlighting any more, or why grep doesn't highlight matched lines any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing that makes `ls` use colors is the `alias` set by the default `bash` config, something like this:

```
alias ls="ls --color=auto"
```

This is generally in `/etc/bash.bashrc` or `~/.bashrc`.  It is possible that one of those files got corrupted when your system crashed.  Do this in your VM:

```
sudo touch /forcefsck
```

And reboot it.  Then check those files.

Comment: And grep is alias grep="grep --color" :)

Comment: Ah, I think I see the problem. I had added a .bash_profile for another purpose, and I think, given this file, it wasn't sourcing .bashrc. Your explanation helped me track down the problem, and I've now added the source .bashrc to my .bash_profile. This answer also helped: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/820517/bashrc-at-ssh-login

Answer (score 1):

"syntax highlighting" in bash for ls command is controled by --color switch

If you want to add to your bash edit ~/.bashrc file. This is how end of my .bashrc looks like:

```
alias ls='ls --color=always'
alias less='less -r'
```

to force reading of .bashrc just start new bash shell or logout and login

this 2 aliases will make command:

```
ls -al | less
```

have color, also you can add something like this:

```
alias l='ls -al --color=always | less -r'
```

to just type l and to have color directory output and page-per-page output.